# JSFiddle not working in all browsers and all fiddles

Tags: jsfiddle

I am trying to open jsfiddle to see demos for some questions on StackOverflow or any other place, but when I open it and it opens normally, but the place where it has to run says this message:

> fiddle.jshell.net’s server IP address could not be found.
>   [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU1ZG.png)

I tried to create my own fiddle and trying in different browsers(I use chrome), but the same problem happened. This is really annoying since jsFiddle is everywhere. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe late but, earlier I had the same problem.
But, I hope that this will help future visitor.
I fixed it just by :

1. Checking my Proxy
2. Using VPN

Answer (score 0):

if you tried other ways but not working **try these:**

-Clearing browser cache.

-Using VPN ( browsec extension is the best).

-reinstalling the browser.